# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 columns

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Boostrap 3 as a basis for my front end and I'm running into an issue using the grid columns that I'm not sure how to fix.

I'm printing out a feed using a loop in PHP and for each feed I'm echoing:

```
<? foreach($feed as $post) { ?>
    <div class='col-lg-6'>
        <?= $post ?>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

This works great except when I have a post that is longer than one previous or the one proceeding it. This causes a bunch of whitespace to be placed between posts in my left most column because my right column is pushing the next row down. Is there anyway to get around this so I can always have my columns and rows line up right after one another?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$posts=0;
$colums=array();
foreach($feed as $post) 
{ 
$colums[$posts%2] .= '<div>'.$post.'</div>';
$posts++;
} 
?>
<div class='col-lg-6'>
   <?=$colums[0]?>  
</div>
<div class='col-lg-6'>
   <?=$colums[1]?>   
</div>
<?
```

Answer (score 0):

for lists and grid you should use bootstrap thumbnails instead of repeating col-md-6. See here for [thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails)

Use this code :

```
<div class="row">
 <? foreach($feed as $post) { ?>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <?= $post ?>
   </div>
 </div>
<? } ?>
</div>
```